# What theory should I apply to the shift of sunlight?

Tags: magic, weather, sunlight

The world consists of two separate lands, one ruled by Caniform tribes the other Feliform, divided by a sky scraping mountain range.

The setting is a mix of ancient Egypt, Iron Age and prehistoric tribes. I'm not even sure what the world actually looks like besides this one island I have created.

With the mountains in the middle, I designed the map to resemble scales to represent balance in nature as the tribes are all predatory related. One side we have wolf and dog like predators, the other side are the cat predators. If these "scales" become unbalanced I want one side to suffer in darkness. This causes the main confrontation and this is what brings these two factions together which creates the premise of my novel.

Life is prosperous on both sides for some time until a shift in energy is created by an antagonist. And darkness falls upon the West causing them to journey across the dangerous mountain range to seek light.

So my question is what scientific reason or magical reasoning can I use to explain the shifting in sunlight?

My characters' intelligence of space and time are going to be limited, so I want a convincing answer that relates to themes of the novel. Making sure to take into account my characters' basis of knowledge and understanding of the world.

Comment: These are two totally different questions. One is about magic and nature, the other is about physics and orbits. Please choose only one, and edit the other out.

Comment: I'm unsure how a mountain, no matter how huge is going to prevent all light from reaching the land on one side of it.

Comment: Is this a flat world, or a round planet, like the Earth...which is a sphere. Not flat.

Comment: @Muuski A better approximation for the Earth is as an oblate sphereoid.

Comment: If you want an answer from scientific perspective, look for "tidal lock" around here - there are lots and lots of discussions.

Comment: @sphennings I get the feeling you're fun at parties ;)

Comment: Someone needs to take his flag hammer away. This is a very reasonable world building question. Secondly it's specific. "what allows me to explain what I want to happen" and "what side effects should I be aware of". The entire question is answered by handing the Asker the term "tidal locking" and pointing them to similar discussions.

Comment: @Stephan - providing that the question asks for a scientific answer. "magic" tag here implies that "flat world" options are at least equally viable.

Comment: Agreed, but the impact will be the same, just with the hot and cold regions on a plane rather than opposite sides of a sphere. My complaint is with the unwarranted hold.

Comment: I am puzzled by the "magic" tag, and also by phrases like "changes the nature of the sun" and "What would the sun actually have to do" suggesting that the sun is moving differently and possibly deliberately. Generally, the normal model is planets moving around a sun, not the reverse. I think the starting parameters of this world need to be clarified, and the terms of reference within which some answer might be constructed, especially the scope of "magic" applied on a cosmological scale (which has massive implications for scientific approaches).

Comment: None of these commenters has asked you: Is this an "astronomically correct" Sun and Earth? Or do we have something like a fixed, flat Earth with a "flying lightbulb" or chariot-driven Sun?

Comment: If you're allowing magical reasons than anything goes. The stars aren't right, one region was cursed by the lord of light, a trickster stole the light, ancient ritual run amok, ancient ritual behaving as expected, Steve got drunk and cast control light, a wizard did it, perturbations in the widget field, an imbalance of the humors, too much yang, etc... If you want to ask questions about magic you need to provide the constraints to your magic system otherwise the question will be too broad.

Comment: What kind of "unbalance" we are talking about here? What kind of "scales" we are talking about here? Is this a metaphorical scale? A region that's formed like a scale? Or what?

Comment: This question has been recommended for reopening, but I cannot vote to do so.  I apologize, but I cannot see how your edit is any less broad than your original question.  You're basically asking us to invent the rules of your world for you without any scope or limitation.  "Fishing for ideas" questions are common here, but they must be scoped such that they meet the expectations of StackExchange's one-question-one-best-answer format.  You must explain the rules of your magic and the rules of your world, or we really can't help you further.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is called [Tidal Locking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking).

Short answer is death by massive storms followed by death of other sorts.

The people in your world would somehow (either magically or scientifically) tidally lock their planet. The [first chapter](https://io9.gizmodo.com/xkcds-creator-explains-what-would-happen-if-earth-stopp-1625068208) of Randall Monroe's book covers a similar question and it's widespread impact.

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29182) addresses it in detail.

With the sun heating only one side, you'd end up with some pretty serious radiation and windstorms on the hot side, followed by snowballing of the cold side, and torrential storms of all sorts at the rim of light and dark.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing how the sun behaves, I'd suggest something far less drastic - total cloud cover. Since magic exists, you could easily handwave it and say that somehow the clouds are thick enough to make it perpetually night. There would still be a day/night cycle of heating and cooling, even if very little visible light made it through the clouds, and it would also allow the other side of the mountains to be completely normal. Then your characters merely need to move the clouds to the other side of the mountains in order to change which side is light and which side is dark.

Much simpler than trying to muck with the orbital mechanics of your planet.